# how to change order status to complete and redirect to download page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress Woocommerce website that sells virtual downloadable products with some blockchain payment method in my custom payment gateway,

I need to handle a code while customer is in payment page in my website and call an Ajax to check if payment is completed and confirmed or not.

When Ajax get answer that shows payment confirmed (in blockchain) I need to update order status to completed and return thank you page with download link of my product.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  
if (!empty($order)) {
     
     $order->update_status( 'completed' );

}
```

with this code I can update order status to 'completed' but I don't know how to return thank-you page with Download link for my Virtual Downloadable Product...

I can just redirect to

```
window.location.href = "'.get_home_url().'/checkout/order-received/";
```

but here there is not any download link.

Comment: window.location.href = "'.get_home_url().'/checkout/order-received/";

What do you think this does? It will just redirect you to currentsite.com/.get_home_url().'/checkout/order-received/
If I believe correctly.

Comment: yes it goes to "Thank you. Your order has been received." page,
i wrote this js in my php file, i want download link of my product shows but i dont find action to get that url

Comment: Why do you want to leave the order-received page first and then come back to it later? If you're already using an Ajax call, why not stay on that page and check for payment through Ajax. Then you don't need to redirect back.

Comment: think i'm in https://example.com/checkout/order-pay/229/?key=wc_order_S0tPYKfQik2c0 i'm checking order is paid or not (in blockchain using ajax), after i get payment paid successfully in blockchain i want to show my customer my product link, where and how can i show him/her? by redirection or not (popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried:

```
 $this->get_return_url( $order )
```

and now i can redirect user to link mentiones above and user can get download link right after ajax answer with download link.